# Закрывать выпадающий див при двойном клике или клике вне дива

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Морочусь целый день, ничего не получатеся ((
Функцию показать блок сделал, работает! Но закрыть при двойном клике и вне блока не работает ( Так же проблема не могу найти функцию что бы выполняла select ( то есть выбрать способ оплаты!!
ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!!

```
<div class="x-order-form-row">
    <div class="x-order-form-row__label">Способ оплаты:</div>
    <div class="x-order-form-row__field x-order-form-row__field_pos_relative"><div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="payment_option">
        <span class="x-drop-down__value"><span>Выберите способ оплаты</span></span>
        <span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="payment_option" name="payment_option" value="">

        <ul class="x-drop-down__list  js-dropdown">
            <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item">
                <span class="x-drop-down__icon-wrapper">
                    <i class="x-drop-down__icon icon-common_payment"></i></span>
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/privatbank.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Безналичный расчет</span></li>
                    <li class="x-drop-down__list-item js-item"><span class="x-drop-down__icon-wrapper"><i class="x-drop-down__icon icon-common_payment"></i></span>
                    <span class="x-drop-down__text"><img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi/images/Без названия.png" width="25px" alt="альтернативный текст">Наложенный платеж</span></li></ul></div></div></div>
            <script src="http://yastatic.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="wp-content/themes/Divi/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                    $('.x-order-form-row__field').click(function(){
                    $('.x-drop-down__list').addClass('x-drop-down__list_active');

                    });
                    $('mouseup').click(function(){
                    $('.x-drop-down__list').removeClass('x-drop-down__list_active');

                    });




            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
        }
    });
```

Разобрался как показать и скрыть меню при двойном клике и вне дива!! Теперь буду искать каким образом сделать выбор пункта оплаты!